# How to extract group of numbers from a phrase using regex?

Tags: regex, match

I have multiple sentences which look like the following sentence - 
`069054 my name is black fox, $1234. phone number:1234567`

I need to extract to extract the first word (or numbers, in this example its 069054).

The conditions that needs to be met are:

1. it should only consist of 6 digits.
2. It should be the first thing in the sentence.
3. If it has more or less digits, i should ignore it.
4. should only consist of numbers, no chars allowed

Here is what i have, but its not working out for me.

```
^([\d]{6})$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regex you are looking for:

```
^(\d{6})(?!\d)
```

Just remove the `$` from the end and replace it with `(?!\d)`. It means the six digits which are not followed by any digit.

If you wish to avoid picking digits from input like `123456xyz` then use this one:

```
^(\d{6})(?![\da-zA-Z])
```